# How to download a file using jQuery

Tags: jquery, download

I have a html button that calls a Jquery function. This function calls a [web Method] in my code-behind.  This Server-code will create (if need be) a file to be downloaded.  I return to the JQuery call the URL of my downloadable file.

This works when the file is an AVI file.

When I try to do it with an ogg file it is played in the browser Window.

How can I force a download from JQuery instead of playing the file?

My Code:

**[Web Method]**

```
public static ArrayList DownloadClip(string ClipValue, string SessionID,string Extension)
{
ListItem _item2 = new ListItem();
_item2.Text = 'MediaFilename';
_item2.Value = "OK";
_arr.Add(_item2);
return _arr;
}
```

**[In ASP.NET Mark-Up Page]**
This is just the code snippet that is for this part..

```
success: function (msg) {
$.each(msg.d, function () {
 if (this['Text'] == "ERROR") {
  $theDiv.html(this['Value']);
  return;
 }
 else {
  url = this['Text'];
  window.location = url;
 }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to do this client-side. If you search around for a way of forcing a download server-side you'll probably have more success.

Comment: Hi, you were correct. Instead of a direct download I returned a link to a ASHX page which in turn returns the file as bytes.  Thanks..